# How to use placeholders at IN() clause when there is other placeholders?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, parameter-passing

Here is my code:

```
$selected_tags_arr = ["PHP", "CSS", "JAVA"];
$part_of_tag = "MyS";
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($selected_tags_arr) - 1) . '?';
$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("SELECT name, usage_guidance, total_used_num
                            FROM tags
                            WHERE
                            ( name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR
                            usage_guidance LIKE CONCAT(?, '%') ) AND
                            name NOT IN ($in)");
$stmt->execute(array($part_of_tag, $part_of_tag, $selected_tags_arr));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

It doesn't work because of syntax error. How can I fix it?

As you see, I have some other parameters *(except `$selected_tags_arr` array)* which I need to pass them. That's when the problem occurs.

**Note:** Maybe sometimes `$selected_tags_arr` array be an empty array.

Comment: You need to post *the syntax error*. There are other problems with the code, e.g.  `execute` expects a flat array, not a matrix.

Comment: You're sending an array within an array. Try merging `$selected_tags_arr` into an array with the other variables first.

Comment: `IN (list)` is *notoriously* hard to parameterize in every language except, gasp, ColdFusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as no one bothered to provide an example. Like aynber said, you need to merge arrays. So the following code should be fine:

```
$stmt->execute(array_merge([$part_of_tag,$part_of_tag], $selected_tags_arr));
```

there could be a problem though, if, like you said, $selected_tags_arr could be empty. It will cause a syntax error.

The remedy depends on the result you want. if you want that your query finds nothing if array is empty, then change your code like this:

```
$in  = $selected_tags_arr ? str_repeat('?,', count($selected_tags_arr) - 1) . '?' : 'NULL';
```

Comment: Thx +1, it woks perfectly in the most of times, except when `$selected_tags_arr` array equals empty like `[]`, in this case it doesn't  work, do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Actually I got the idea .. but when I set `NULL`, as you said, the query doesn't find anything .. while I want to disable *only* this part of the query `AND name NOT IN ($in)` when that array in empty .. So do you know what should I set instead of `NULL` ?

Comment: @stack you will have to take out the whole part with IN in this case. Or, rather, add it conditionally